# How could I make an input if/else check if something is PART of an input?

Tags: python

Ok, **Im new to Python,** as in only been coding in it for ~2.5 weeks. Please remember that in your answers. :D.

Im currently trying to make a program, as actually MAKING programs with stuff Iv been learning online helps me to learn it (Extremely basic Ubuntu terminal emulator, why not ;p) and I need to make an input that checks if something in an if/else statement is in the input.

Example:

```
 input1 = input("test@ubuntu:~$")
 if input1 == "sudo":
     input2 = input("[sudo] enter password for test:")
```

But have the if statement trigger if sudo/cd/anything is mentioned ANYWHERE in the input. 
If someone put in "sudo cd / " it would trigger because the input has Sudo in it. Again, Im new to this language as a whole, so please no "duh, you just do this, you should have known that" answers please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "sudo" in input1:
    ...
```

This checks substring inclusion as well as appearance in a sequence (list, tuple, string, etc.).

For more general use, to find if any disallowed term is in the input:

```
bad_list = [
    "sudo",
    "cd",
    "/",
    "anything"
]

if any([word in input for word in bad_list]):
```

The **any** (logical or) and **all** (logical and) operators go through a list of values, taking them as Booleans (checking the "truthy" property of each element).  The stuff in brackets is called a "list comprehension", and it's a way of building a list by description -- sort of coding a **for** loop *inside* a list.

Comment: Thank you! I just tested it out, and it worked. I'll set this as best answer in 9 minutes when it lets me do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Prune's answer is what you asked for. But for what you want to do, I believe `.starstwith('sudo')` could be helpful.

```
if input1.strip().starstwith('sudo'):
   ...
```

Because otherwise, if you run something like `echo 'sudo'` for example, it'll ask you the password.

*Note: the `.strip` removes any spaces/line break at the beginning or at the end of the string*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply as well. @Prune got what I needed, but this could help me out too, a bit easier to quickly sort if something has sudo or similiar in it.